# New styles added to Word 2010 (Heading 1 + Not Bold)

Tags: vba, vsto, word-2010

In Word 2010 the new styles are created automatically, I would like to suppress this behaviour.
For eg: the text with style "Heading 1" after formatting say ctrl+B to remove the bold, the Word creates a new style called "Heading 1 + Not Bold"

Actually I want to switch oof this behaviour from VSTO at application level.
Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Word is not creating new styles but is displaying (within the Styles Pane) styles that also have direct formatting (which is formatting applied after the application of a style). The Options link on the bottom of the Styles Pane will display the below dialog box, which contains the style display choices:

[image: Style Pane Options]

To turn off the display of direct formatting via VBA (which can be adapted for VSTO depending on the language you are using):

```
 'Turn off display of character direct formatting
 ActiveDocument.FormattingShowFont = False
 'Turn off display of paragraph direct formatting
 ActiveDocument.FormattingShowParagraph = False
```

Additionally, one can control which styles are displayed with the `FormattingShowFilter` property. For example, to only display the styles in use in the active document:

```
ActiveDocument.FormattingShowFilter = wdShowFilterStylesInUse
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above solutions works perfectly. Now I have style added to my Quick Access toolbar and this still displays the formatted style. Any idea?

Comment: The Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) allows the creation of configurable buttons. Are you saying you created a QAT button that applies a style and you do not want the style to appear in the Quick Styles Gallery and the Styles Pane? The solution above only removes the display of styles that have additional formatting placed on top of them (direct formatting). To remove the display of a style that has no extra formatting, one must use both style properties `Visibility = True` and `UnhideWhenUsed = False`. They will stop the display of a style as long as "Select styles to show" is not set to All Styles

Answer (score 1):

You might also uncheck "paragraph level formatting" in the Style Pane Options dialog box.  Turning off both font and paragraph "formatting to show" is the only way I can use Word.  Otherwise, the direct formatting added by multiple authors obscures the styles you really want.

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided affect the display, but not the root behaviour of Word.  If you want to suppress this behaviour at the application level set the Application option to Keep Track of Formatting to off (Tools > Option > Advanced > Editing Options > Keep track of formatting.).

Answer (score 1):

File / Options / Proofing / Auto Correct Options... (button) / AutoFormat As You Type (tab) / uncheck Define styles based on your formatting